# how many iterations in breakpoint analysis (bfast)?

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

I am doing a breakpoint (using `bfast`) analysis of several Vegetation Index time series (15 years time series; 340 images; MODIS). I have around 20.000 time series objects I want to analyse.

I am already working parallel (using `foreach`) but it is still very time consuming. And of course the more iterations, the more time needed. Below a short example of going from 1 to 3 iterations and time used respectively (for 50 time series). (sorry, in german, the last one of system.time() is "elapsed"). `ndvi.ts` is my `mts` object - each column containing a time series.

```
> str(ndvi.ts)
 Time-Series [1:340, 1:20054] from 1.43 to 16.2: -0.1213 0.0781 0.3295 -0.0073 0.4163 ...

> system.time(bfast.ls <- foreach(n=1:50, .packages = "bfast", .options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
+   y <- bfast(ndvi.ts[,n], h=rdist,season="harmonic",max.iter=1)
+   return(y)
+ })
  |=======================================================================================| 100%       User      System verstrichen 
       1.00        1.34       85.15 
> system.time(bfast.ls <- foreach(n=1:50, .packages = "bfast", .options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
+   y <- bfast(ndvi.ts[,n], h=rdist,season="harmonic",max.iter=2)
+   return(y)
+ })
  |=======================================================================================| 100%       User      System verstrichen 
       1.15        1.44      164.80 
> system.time(bfast.ls <- foreach(n=1:50, .packages = "bfast", .options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
+   y <- bfast(ndvi.ts[,n], h=rdist,season="harmonic",max.iter=3)
+   return(y)
+ })
  |=======================================================================================| 100%       User      System verstrichen 
       1.36        1.60      225.19
```

So I am wondering if there is a rule of thumb, at what number of iterations I get no "better" results?

I did not find anything online regarding the `max.iter` parameter setting. Already using `max.iter=3` would slow me down a lot. Of course, if there is some point in which I could make my code faster I am glad to hear that, too.

Comment: I think you might be better on a more programming oriented site especially for your question about parallelism. An alternative might be R-help or one of the more specific R lists.

Comment: Yeah my idea was that the outcoming "problem" is more a programming one, but the underlying cause (the iterations) is more of a statistical question. But I think I will try at stackoverflow as well .

Comment: There is one specialised in ecology which might be the first thing to try.

Comment: Do you mean the biology one? Or is there another one?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-ecology Note ecology is not my field so you should browse the archives to make sure it is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: https://github.com/appelmar/scalbf-wur
There's a C++ port of the strucchange relevant functions, it should get you up to speed.

Thomas